# JavaScript - Outputting a line with Document Write

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am trying to output a line with the javascript Document.Write function, however, on Submitting the form, the line just flashes and disappears

any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Validation</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkAge() { 
                var x = document.forms['myForm']['age'].value;
                if(x < 18) {
                    document.write("<p>You are too Young. Form NOT submitted</p>");
                } else {
                    document.write("Form sent successfully");
                }
            }

            function tips() {
                alert("Please enter your Name in the name Box, \nand Your age in the Age box.\nYou have to be Over 18 to submit the form");
            }
        </script>

        <form id="myForm" action="formvalidation.html" onsubmit="checkAge();">    
            Name: <input type="text" name="text" id="name">
            Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="button" value="Help" id="hBtn" onclick="tips();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use document.write after the page has loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @epascarello How can i display that text without it?

Comment: innerHTML/appendChild/etc

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `document.write()` to print on current page.

Calling `document.write()` will automatically call `document.open()` which clears the current document and thus your present content is cleared.

Alternatively you can use an html `<div id="result"></div>` and change it's value like this,

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Some Text";
```

Comment: What can I do instead? That is what I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Return false on the handler to not make the page refresh on submit:

```
 <form id="myForm" action="formvalidation.html" onsubmit="checkAge();return false;">
```

Comment: the page becomes empty and shows just the text - how can i show the text on the page with the form